# What is the easiest way to organize luggage?

Tags: algorithm

I have a probleme about organizing luggage. I know to volume of the luggage and each item that I will put in to the luggage. When I calculate it I see that it is possible to fit them in to the luggage. But I don’t know how to do it? (Also I know the shapes of the items.)

Comment: You may have a look at the [knapsack problem at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). If you only know the volume of the items and not their shape, then all you can do is simply check if sum of item-volumes <= luggage volume.

Comment: That problem would sound like it's np-complete, if done optimally. So, there is no easy way

Comment: If you are allowed to stay suboptimally, then just add up all luggage heights and check that they are smaller than your allowed volume is high. Check whether the widest item is less wide than your luggage space. If both is true, it fits, definitely. Will this throw out a lot of things that would actually fit? Sure. Is it easy. Also sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is well known enough to deserve a Wikipedia article: [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

Quoting the article:

> The knapsack problem is interesting from the perspective of computer science for many reasons:
>
> - The decision problem form of the knapsack problem (Can a value of at least V be achieved without exceeding the weight W?) is NP-complete, thus there is no known algorithm that is both correct and fast (polynomial-time) in all cases.
> - While the decision problem is NP-complete, the optimization problem is not, its resolution is at least as difficult as the decision problem, and there is no known polynomial algorithm which can tell, given a solution, whether it is optimal (which would mean that there is no solution with a larger V, thus solving the NP-complete decision problem).
> - There is a pseudo-polynomial time algorithm using dynamic programming.
> - There is a fully polynomial-time approximation scheme, which uses the pseudo-polynomial time algorithm as a subroutine, described below.
> - Many cases that arise in practice, and "random instances" from some distributions, can nonetheless be solved exactly.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

In its full geometric embodiment (objects of known 3D shape), the packing problem is virtually intractable if you want an exact solution.

You must simplify it, for instance by approximating the objects by a bounding box and disallowing arbitrary rotations. Then, there is no much better way than brute force trials.